# C# How to cast List<object[]> into List<customClass>

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my code .Can be run in Linqpad.

```
void Main(){

   List<Object> listobj=new List<object>{
   new object[]{"A01001","sucess","on"},
   new object[]{"A01002","fail","off"}};
   listobj.Dump();

   var second = listobj.Cast<RowItem>();
   second.Dump();
}

public class RowItem {
   public string GOODS_ID { get; set; }
   public string AUDIT_STATUS { get; set; }
   public string APPLY_STATUS { get; set; }
}
```

I want convert `List<object>` to `List<RowItem>`, but when I am using the cast method, it returns an error `cannot convert type 'System.Object[]' to class RowItem`

Is this possible, or is there another way of accomplishing this?

Thank you.

Comment: you are trying convert string array(indirectly) to RowItem object. that doesnt work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `listobj`'s type is incorrect at many levels. The type is a collection of object arrays concealed as object array. If you want to continue with the same type, here is the code that will work.

```
void Main()
{

    List<Object> listobj = new List<object>{
   new object[]{"A01001","sucess","on"},
   new object[]{"A01002","fail","off"}};
    listobj.Dump();

    var second = listobj.Cast<object[]>().Select(l => new RowItem { 
                                                        GOODS_ID=l[0].ToString(),
                                                        AUDIT_STATUS=l[1].ToString(),
                                                        APPLY_STATUS=l[2].ToString() 
                                                });
    second.Dump();
}

public class RowItem
{
    public string GOODS_ID { get; set; }
    public string AUDIT_STATUS { get; set; }
    public string APPLY_STATUS { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you can take a look at this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075003/convert-array-to-custom-object-list-c-sharp